# Can we have comments shown when editing a post in the review queue

Tags: feature-request, comments, review, edits, low-quality-posts

I recently came across an answer in the low quality posts review queue on [Interpersonal Skills](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/questions). Some comments had been left asking for clarification which were subsequently answered (also in comments) by the author of the answer. Editing these responses into the body of the post would work towards solving the problems that got it flagged in the first place, so I choose the edit option in the review. When the editor dialog opened, I went to look at the comments to get the information I needed to edit only to find that the comments section had disappeared.

[image: Missing comments section]

This is a different experience from editing a post when you are viewing it outside of the review queue.

[image: Comments section shown]

It's a bit cumbersome to have to open the post in a new tab and then switch back and forth between two tabs to look at the content of the comments that I'm trying to edit into a post. Having the comments still be shown in the review queue when doing an edit would make it a lot easier to handle this type of review task.

Comment: It would be nice to have this for every reviewer, not just those with full editing privileges.